# Linq: return List contained List

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class:

```
public class BigClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public List<LittleClass> LittleClassList { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to return List of its instances in one request to DataBase? This approach invokes many requests to DataBase:

```
List<BigClass> data = context.Table1_Name ...

foreach(var item in data)
{
    item.LittleClassList = context.Table2_Name ...
}
```

Lambda syntax is preferred. Thank you.

Comment: Your post intent is unclear. please clarify so someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from big in context.TableA
from little in big.LittleClassList
select little;
```

And in extension format

```
Context.TableA.Where(...).SelectMany(x=>x.LittleClassList);
```

Comment: Yeap your way will be better. Up!

Answer (score -1):

```
   List<LittleClass> littleClassesOfListBigClasses = new List<LittleClass>();

   context.BigClass.ToList().ForEach(e=>littleClassesOfListBigClasses.AddRange(e.LittleClassList));
```

**Specialy for `Dave A`.**

What I think OP wants:
He want to take all `LittleClass`es stored in db by one lambda-expression.

Explanation about how does my code works:

1) I use EF(entity framework). If you dont know what it is you can read information 
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef). In the question I see that the OP knows what is EF and how to use it, so I didnt find a need to explain.
2) I take all data from table `BigClass` from the DB and bring it as List(in 1 query)
3) I used ForEach(from Linq) to go through the returned `BigClass` list and add the all `LittleClass`es to the `littleClassesOfListBigClasses`

Notice also you can add `Where` before to `ToList` to get not all data stored in `BigClass` table but only a part, it will look something like this:

```
context.BigClass.Where(some lambda-expression).ToList()
```

So my answer is clear now?

Comment: Please, when you do '-' write why you think it is a bad solution?

Comment: 1) The OP is unclear 2) your Post is a shot-in-dark guess at vague proposition. No value to anyone.

Comment: What are you talking about? After using those 2 lines you will get the the all `LittleClass` stored in db in littleClassesOfListBigClasses.

Comment: If you will waste some time to read the question you will find this asnwer usefull. Or you can also dont understand my answer if you never seen the lambda-expressions. If you dont understand something please dont critic it.

Comment: I was as clear as I could be. The urge to help people is commendable. The urge to shoot in every direction is not. If you feel you can educate me out of my ignorance, please do.

Comment: I shoot only in the directions where i definetly know how to do it. This code was tested before posting. So if you please stop being child and stop doing "-" just because I gave you "-" in another question(I explained why i did it and you agreed with me) i will be very gratitude. If you cant understand something in my answer feel free to ask for the explanation. In my previviouse comments I explained the work of my code. If you dont know what is `ForEach` or  `ToList` or what is `EF` feel free to use the google. Or ask me, I will try to help.

Comment: Are you still dont understand my asnwer?

Comment: I see you CANT take criticism. Feel free to edit your question explaining what you think the OP wanted and how you met it and I'll vote it back up and cry in my ignorance ;)

Comment: I can take criticism, BUT when the man who does the critic can argue his opinion!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24869/discussion-between-maris-and-dave-a)